# Multiple Column & Multiple Header & Font Size Issue in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to prepare a slide which include a table.  The table includes multiple columns and multiple row.  The text is going beyond the cell. The table is beyond the length of the slide.  The code for the table is as below.

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}}
    \hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Designation of Component} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{In coarse grained soil} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {In fine grained soil} \\ 
    \hline 
    {} & \% Fines & Terminology & \% Accessories coarse fraction & Terminology & \%Sand or Gravel & Terminology \\ 
    \hline 
    • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
    \hline 
    • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
    \hline 
    • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

Can anyone help to fix the table.[image: Table with multiple columns and rows and font size issu]

Comment: If the table is too wide, I'd consider transposing it. Some advice: look at the booktabs documentation, and read the first chapter.

Comment: What kind of contents will the individual columns contain? Numbers, single words or lenghty text that needs line breaks? How many rows will your table contain?

Comment: length text and it need to wrapped up in the cell.  other issue is changing fontsize of the text.